# Maven: Failed to read artifact descriptor for every project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

http://prntscr.com/eevy7b
http://pastebin.com/HkQHV45Y <- Console output

I have no clue why this is happening :/
here is my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.ulmc</groupId>
    <artifactId>UnleashedSkills</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>clean package install</defaultGoal>
        <sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>.</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>plugin.yml</include>
                    <include>config.yml</include>
                    <include>choppingTools.yml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>dmulloy2-repo</id>
            <url>http://repo.dmulloy2.net/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>ulmc-repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.ulmc.net</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>pex-repo</id>
            <url>http://pex-repo.aoeu.xyz</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>stealthyone-repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.stealthyone.com/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.comphenix.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>ProtocolLib-API</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>craftbukkit</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>main</groupId>
            <artifactId>Main</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.connorlinfoot</groupId>
            <artifactId>BountifulAPI</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.ulmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>UnleashedEnhancedMining</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sk89q</groupId>
            <artifactId>worldguard</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sk89q</groupId>
            <artifactId>worldedit</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.ulmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>UnleashedSatchelsRevamped</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations-java5</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This also happens for every other project in my workspace. I've deleted my local repo, and reinstalled the dependencies. Still no prevail. I've tried to run `maven -U clean install` and `maven -X`.

Comment: What's the output of mvn -e clean install command?

Comment: The first step is to get the output from a command line build rather than from an IDE.

Comment: here is the stacktrace as requested: http://pastebin.com/HkQHV45Y
@Kamil

Comment: Update your post accordingly. Not everyone can access pastebin...Furthermore Why have you changed the source directory? Follow the conventions.

Comment: @SageM, please update your post, as it was mentioned by khmarbaise. Generally the output of Maven from command line is much more useful than the screenshot, you placed here, so you should make it available here. Also please check this post, as it seems to be related to your problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ.

Comment: Fixed & Updated
@khmarbaise I'm not using convention because of the type of projects we create and the team I work with. Also, that paste is public so I can't imagine why you wouldn't be able to access it.